# How to affect json serialization through attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class:

```
public class Query
{
    public Query(int[] ids) => IDs = ids;
    public int[] IDs { get; }
}
```

Let's say I have:

```
var query = new Query(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query)
```

I need the serialization result to be:

```
json == "[1, 2, 3]"
```

By default I get:

```
json == "{ "IDs": [1, 2, 3] }"
```

I have only access to the `Query` class and I can only affect the serialization process through it. Is there a way to use some JsonAttributes or something to force the class to be serialized into the state I need it to be, when passed to regular `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method?

#### Clarification:

I can not just do `JsonConver.SerializeObject(Query.IDs)`, or anything like that. The Query object is sent down the pipeline (and it has to be this whole object), which somewhere in the middle serializes it and sends as a request to a web API that expects only an array. I cannot change the pipeline, nor the API, due to other systems relying on it, so the only way left for me, is to somehow setup a json serializer on the `Query` class itself.

Comment: I can't serialize only the array. This is a piece of a bigger pipeline, where I input the  Query object and, in the middle it's serialized into json, to be sent over to an API, that expects just the IDs. I don't want to go too deep into details, but gist of it is - I have Query object on the input, and I need only the IDs serialized on the output - I can't, currently, change the rest of the system.

Comment: The pipeline input expects an object of class that implements a certain interface (ommited in the question for readability). That object is sent down it, magic happens, and at some point it's serialized and sent to an external web API that expects just an array of IDs, as a json. This one API is badly designed, it should've expected the Query object on the input, but I cannot change it, I have no access to it's code, so I need to find a way around it. I can only work with the Query class, and I cannot send the IDs down the pipeline, since that wouldn't implement the special interface.

Comment: You can specifiy custom serialisers for JSON.net, have a look at  - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

So, using the Sam's advice I used a CustomJsonConverter:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomQueryConverter))]
public class Query
{
    public Query(int[] ids)
    {
        IDs = ids;
    }

    public int[] IDs { get; }
}

public class CustomQueryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Query);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);

        int[] items = array?.Select(jv => (int)jv).ToArray();
        return new Query(items);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var query = value as Query;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, query.IDs);
    }
}
```

And test that tests it:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var query = new Query(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);

    Assert.Equal("[1,2,3]", json);

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>(json);

    Assert.Equal(1, deserialized.IDs[0]);
    Assert.Equal(2, deserialized.IDs[1]);
    Assert.Equal(3, deserialized.IDs[2]);
}
```